# Zoom on SVG without scaling items

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm working on a special case, I have a site plan (of building), and I should place some "markers" on it.

These markers are **foreignObject** (cause of some special content). They must not be scaled on zooming, just translated.

I have:

```
this.svg = d3.select("svg");

var width = $("svg").width();
var height = $("svg").height();
var that = this;

this.view = this.svg.select("g");
this.container = this.svg.append("g"); // I put my foreignObjects here

this.svg.call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 40])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width , height]])
    .on("zoom", function () {
        that.view.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    })
).on("click", function() {
    $(".marker-chart").remove();
});
//Iterate to instantiate markers
```

And my markers are instantiate like that :

```
function(config) {
    var that = this;
    var myForeignObject = this.container.append("foreignObject");
    //Moving item
    myForeignObject.attr("x", config.x)
        .attr("y", config.y)
        .call(d3.drag().on("start", function () {
            if( that.isEditingMode ) {
                d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
            }
        }).on("drag", function () {
            if( that.isEditingMode ) {
                d3.select(this).attr("x", d3.event.x).attr("y",d3.event.y);
            }
        }).on("end", function () {
            if( that.isEditingMode ) {
                d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
            }
        }));

    var myDiv = myForeignObject.append("xhtml:body");
    myDiv.attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

    //Some stuff : adding element in foreignObject
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle so that we can play around.

Comment: Just change the dimensions of the foreign object based on d3.event.scale value. So on scale, thisWidth = thisWidth / d3.event.scale;

Comment: @thatOneGuy Thanks, I'm trying on this way; for the JsFiddle, I have try, but lot of bugs appear ...

Comment: @thatOneGuy It seem good, Firefox need a negative translation also (after scalling), thanks you ;)

Comment: no problem, glad i could help